# HTTP 415 error when using spring mvc RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a JQuery grid plugin to represent data on UI. The add row functionality sends a form encoded url request to the server.

THe mapping is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public CDto addC(@RequestBody CDto c) {
    // Write to DB.
}
```

I am getting a HTTP 415 error.

If I use the HttpServletRequest as parameter, then I do not get a 415

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public CDto addC(HttpServletRequest r) {
    // Write to DB.
}
```

The CDto is a simple pojo with default constructor.

I want to use the RequestBody annotation to parse the body. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Show the front end call

Comment: 415 http statis code means unsupported media type ! You are not sending the expected media type (application/form-url-encoded in your case)

Comment: check whether your mvc xml has <mvc:annotation-driven /> or import Jackson jar?

Comment: Replace `@RequestBody` with `@ModelAttribute`, If you're sending a `form` and want to bind it to a model

Comment: @AliDehghani `@ModelAttribute` works! Thanks!